# How to insert dynamic list items into SwiftUI list?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

This is my body:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            MonthElementView(month: month)
            ServiceElementView(service: month.services.first!)
            ServiceElementView(service: month.services.first!)
        }
    }
}
```

And it works.

But I need to display here `ServiceElementView` for every Service of the Month, and I don't know how to do it with SwiftUI. The following solution doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong `forEach`.

It's…

```
ForEach(month.sortedServices) { service in

}
```

Comment: Why it makes a difference... but ok, it worked perfectly;) Thank you